# Listview is scrolling on iOS but not Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Works fine on iOS, but won't scroll on Android. can you please check what I am doing wrong or any ideas what might cause this, or what to check for?
I tried to add scrollview, added heightRequest, and changed verticalOptions to FillAndExpand but nothing seemed to work

```
<ContentView.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout Margin="0,0,30,0">
            <Entry
                x:Name="searchBar"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,AutoSize"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="WidthProportional"
                BackgroundColor="White"
                HeightRequest="40"
                Placeholder="Enter sensor"
                TextChanged="SearchBar_OnTextChanged"
                TextColor="{DynamicResource RelogixDarkGray}"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <ListView
                x:Name="dataListView"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="5,40,.98,.4"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="SizeProportional"
                BackgroundColor="White"
                CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                HasUnevenRows="True"
                IsVisible="False"
                ItemTapped="ListView_OnItemTapped">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>

                            <StackLayout Margin="5" Padding="0">
                                <Label
                                    BackgroundColor="White"
                                    FontFamily="{StaticResource NormalFont}"
                                    FontSize="16"
                                    Text="{Binding .}"
                                    TextColor="#FF464859"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackLayout>

                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I do not what is you used about `TextColor="{DynamicResource RelogixDarkGray}"` and `FontFamily="{StaticResource NormalFont}"` So I delete it for test.

Then you set the `IsVisible="False"` in your `ListView`, If you set the value to false, it cannot be seen, when you run it, I set it to True.

And you did not set the `ItemsSource="{Binding myModels}"` for your `listview`. You should set it, here is my layout code.

```
<AbsoluteLayout Margin="0,0,30,0">
                <Entry
                x:Name="searchBar"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,AutoSize"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="WidthProportional"
                BackgroundColor="White"
                HeightRequest="40"
                Placeholder="Enter sensor"
                TextChanged="searchBar_TextChanged"

                VerticalOptions="Center" />
                <ListView
                    ItemsSource="{Binding myModels}"
                x:Name="dataListView"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="5,40,.98,.4"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="SizeProportional"
                BackgroundColor="White"
                CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                HasUnevenRows="True"
                IsVisible="True"
                ItemTapped="dataListView_ItemTapped">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>

                                <StackLayout Margin="5" Padding="0">
                                    <Label
                                    BackgroundColor="White"

                                    FontSize="16"
                                    Text="{Binding .}"
                                    TextColor="#FF464859"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                </StackLayout>

                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </AbsoluteLayout>
```

I notice you used MVVM, you should add `BindingContext = new MyModelView();` in the layout background code like this simple.

```
  public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = new MyModelView();
        } 
}
```

Here is `MyModelView.cs`

```
    public class MyModelView
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MyModel> myModels { get; set; }
        public MyModelView()
        {

            myModels = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Prop0="xxx",Prop1="xxx1",Prop2="xxxx2",Prop3=true,Prop4="xxxx4" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Prop0 = "xxx", Prop1 = "xxx1", Prop2 = "xxxx2", Prop3 = true, Prop4 = "xxxx4" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Prop0 = "xxx", Prop1 = "xxx1", Prop2 = "xxxx2", Prop3 = true, Prop4 = "xxxx4" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Prop0 = "xxx", Prop1 = "xxx1", Prop2 = "xxxx2", Prop3 = true, Prop4 = "xxxx4" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Prop0 = "xxx", Prop1 = "xxx1", Prop2 = "xxxx2", Prop3 = true, Prop4 = "xxxx4" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Prop0 = "xxx", Prop1 = "xxx1", Prop2 = "xxxx2", Prop3 = true, Prop4 = "xxxx4" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Prop0 = "xxx", Prop1 = "xxx1", Prop2 = "xxxx2", Prop3 = true, Prop4 = "xxxx4" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Prop0 = "xxx", Prop1 = "xxx1", Prop2 = "xxxx2", Prop3 = true, Prop4 = "xxxx4" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Prop0 = "xxx", Prop1 = "xxx1", Prop2 = "xxxx2", Prop3 = true, Prop4 = "xxxx4" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Prop0 = "xxx", Prop1 = "xxx1", Prop2 = "xxxx2", Prop3 = true, Prop4 = "xxxx4" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Prop0 = "xxx", Prop1 = "xxx1", Prop2 = "xxxx2", Prop3 = true, Prop4 = "xxxx4" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Prop0 = "xxx", Prop1 = "xxx1", Prop2 = "xxxx2", Prop3 = true, Prop4 = "xxxx4" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Prop0 = "xxx", Prop1 = "xxx1", Prop2 = "xxxx2", Prop3 = true, Prop4 = "xxxx4" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Prop0 = "xxx", Prop1 = "xxx1", Prop2 = "xxxx2", Prop3 = true, Prop4 = "xxxx4" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Prop0 = "xxx", Prop1 = "xxx1", Prop2 = "xxxx2", Prop3 = true, Prop4 = "xxxx4" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Prop0 = "xxx", Prop1 = "xxx1", Prop2 = "xxxx2", Prop3 = true, Prop4 = "xxxx4" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Prop0 = "xxx", Prop1 = "xxx1", Prop2 = "xxxx2", Prop3 = true, Prop4 = "xxxx4" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Prop0 = "xxx", Prop1 = "xxx1", Prop2 = "xxxx2", Prop3 = true, Prop4 = "xxxx4" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Prop0 = "xxx", Prop1 = "xxx1", Prop2 = "xxxx2", Prop3 = true, Prop4 = "xxxx4" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Prop0 = "xxx", Prop1 = "xxx1", Prop2 = "xxxx2", Prop3 = true, Prop4 = "xxxx4" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Prop0 = "xxx", Prop1 = "xxx1", Prop2 = "xxxx2", Prop3 = true, Prop4 = "xxxx4" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Prop0 = "xxx", Prop1 = "xxx1", Prop2 = "xxxx2", Prop3 = true, Prop4 = "xxxx4" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Prop0 = "xxx", Prop1 = "xxx1", Prop2 = "xxxx2", Prop3 = true, Prop4 = "xxxx4" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Prop0 = "xxx", Prop1 = "xxx1", Prop2 = "xxxx2", Prop3 = true, Prop4 = "xxxx4" });
        }
    }
```

Here is `MyModel.cs`.

```
    public class MyModel
    {
        public string Prop0 { get; set; }
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
        public bool Prop3 { get; set; }
        public string Prop4 { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]

If I set a binding value for `Label`

```
<Label
                                    BackgroundColor="White"

                                    FontSize="16"
                                    Text="{Binding Prop0}"
                                    TextColor="#FF464859"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]